# Arraylist Index adding with hashmap?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexing, hashmap

Inside the arraylist i need to add hashmap values and i declared
    arralist as

```
public static ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> UploadingArray = new ArrayList<>();
 and map 
Map<String,Object> image_details=new HashMap<>();
and



int imageid;
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
   imageid=i;
   new method()
  }
```

image id will change when this function calling from another activity
   imageid=(another activity).imageid;

```
  new method(){
    image_details.put("imageid",i);
    image_details.put("status","New");
    UploadingArray.add(imageid,image_details);
 }


but the result of UploadingArray like

[0]
id=3;
status=New
[1]
id=3;
status=New
[2]
id=3;
status=New
[3]
id=3;
status=New
```

why the id is same for all position? any one know the issue please help me?
   This is just a model the "i" value will be changed by calling method

Comment: Inside of your method called ``method``, you access the variable ``i``. That variable is *not* the ``i`` from your loop. It seems you have a member variable called ``i`` which is 3 all the time.

Comment: declare new method(int num) instead of new method()

Answer (score 1):

They have the same values because you're adding the **same** object multiple times to your `ArrayList`.

You should create a new `Map` object inside your loop:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    // creating new object on every iteration
    Map<String, Object> imageDetails = new HashMap<>();

    imageDetails.put("imageId", i);
    imageDetails.put("status", "new");

    list.add(imageId, imageDetails);
}
```